# How can accent can be more accurate with bf and query with solr

Tags: solr, scoring, dismax

i work with solr, i can't fix my problem of result's accuracy (q vs bf taking into account accents)

i have a solr index with 2 fields indexed (this is simplified):

```
town, population
Félines, 100
Ferrand, 10000
```

when i query: `q=Fé&qf=town town_ascii&bf=population^2&defType=dismax`
I'd like this order on my results : `Félines > Ferrand`.

When i query: `q=Fe&qf=town town_ascii&bf=population^2&defType=dismax` I'd like this order on my results : `Ferrand  > Félines`

The trouble is that Ferrand beats every time Félines because its population is bigger, how can i solve that? I didn't find how to use the score of the query and use it in `bf` to balance population

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your `schema.xml` but I suppose you're using the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` for the `town_ascii` field. It means that if you're indexing the word Félines the following are the indexed terms:

```
town: Félines
town_ascii: Felines
```

Therefore, you're saying that a match for the `town` field is more important than a match for `town_ascii`. You should change the `qf` parameter to something like `qf=town^3 town_ascii` to give more weight to the `town` field. Then you can adjust the weight depending on what is the desired weight for `town` compared to `population`.